# Changing the Region changes the Language on iOS11?

Tags: ios, internationalization

I'm really confused about changing **Language** verse **Region** on an iPhone running iOS11.

Apple discusses [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SpecifyingPreferences/SpecifyingPreferences.html) about changing the Language and the Region:

> "For iOS, changing the language restarts Springboard and quits running
>   apps. So the next time you launch an iOS app, it uses the new language
>   setting. ... For iOS and Mac, the region and calendar settings can be
>   changed at any time, even when your app is running."

So, I take that to mean that if I change the **Language**, the App will have to be restarted.  But, if I change the **Region**, the App will not have to be restarted.  I've been chasing my tail for an hour or more wondering why my App was shutting down when I was just changing the **Region**.  Then I read the text on the screens, below, a bit closer.

My iPhone is running English (U.S.).  I go to Settings>General>Language & Region.  This is what I see:

[image]

I go to the **Region** button and I click it. And it shows me a long list of countries.  Here's what I see (note it says **Region** at the top of this list):

[image]

I click United Kingdom and then Done at the top right.  Then I see this:

[image]

It is giving me the choice to confirm my selection of English (U.K.) or to stay with English (U.S.).  But note also that it says:

> "Would you like to change the iPhone language to English (U.K.)?"

So, here's my confusion. Why am I being asked to change the **Language** at this point when I'm clearly choosing a **Region**? What am I missing here?

rmaddy made a comment in response to the above:

> You are being asked if you want to update the language in addition to
>   the region change. This is because your current language is US English
>   and you are now choosing a region which generally speaks UK English.
>   So iOS is being helpful and offering you the additional option of
>   changing the language that best suits your new region. If you choose
>   the "Keep ..." option then only the region is updated and not the
>   language.

That made a lot of sense and I thought it was the answer but I'm noting that all of the following scenarios (some of which *only* seem to be changing the Region) still result in my App shutting down and I am having trouble reconciling that fact with the documentation which says:

> For iOS and Mac, the region and calendar settings can be changed at
>   any time, even when your app is running.

**Scenarios which result in my App shutting down:**

1. I change Region from United States to United Kingdom, click Done and
   then choose "Change to English (U.K.).  As per rmaddy's comment, I
   think this changes both the Language and the Region.  App shuts
   down.
2. I change Region from United States to United Kingdom, click Done and
   then choose "Keep English (U.S.).  I think this changes just the
   Region to U.K. but leaves the Language as U.S.  App shuts down.
3. I change Region from United States to U.S. Virgin Islands, click
   Done and then Choose Continue when it says, "Would you like to
   change the region to U.S. Virgin Islands."  App shuts down.

Please note that the app which is shutting down is one I am developing. Written in Objective-C for iPhones and iPads for iOS9 and up.

Comment: What is the app that shuts down?

Comment: The app is one I am developing. Written in Objective-C for iPhones and iPads for iOS9 and up.

Comment: Can you update the question to mention the fact that the app you are referring to is the one you are developing?

Comment: Nimesh Neema - done.

Comment: @NimeshNeema All apps will be shutdown if the language changes. And apparently, now all apps will be shutdown on iOS 11 when the region is changed.

Comment: @rmaddy Are the Developer Documents updated with this fact or the statement is based on observation?

Comment: @NimeshNeema As I commented below my answer, the document linked in the question hasn't been update since iOS 9 came out. I know for a fact that back that a simple region change did not terminate running apps. In fact a running app could listen for a change of region so it could respond to the change in locale. The OP claims that now under iOS 11, a region change also causes apps to terminate just as a language change does. While I haven't taken the time to verify, I have no reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I hope you mean against the documentation because the iOS behavior isn't going to change.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, documentation.

Comment: @rmaddy, I have filed the bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are being asked if you want to update the language *in addition* to the region change. This is because your current language is US English and you are now choosing a region which generally speaks UK English. So iOS is being helpful and offering you the additional option of changing the language that best suits your new region. If you choose the "Keep ..." option then only the region is updated and not the language.

Comment: Whew, thanks for that.  It seems to me that hat is a not-very-clear interface.

Comment: rmaddy's answer looked good and, indeed, it worked as he suggested.  

But my basic quandary remains.  The Apple documents say that the region CAN be changed and that the App will continue running.  But, if I make any change to Region, my App shuts down. I've updated my original question above to reflect this new information.

Comment: Keep in mind that the article you linked to hasn't been updated since September of 2015 when iOS 9 came out. You can't expect iOS 11 to function exactly the same as iOS 9.